# Entity Framework: How to group class with lots of properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I inherited a largish EF Core application, where some Table have nearly 90 rows. Most of these rows are related, e.g. there 20 rows for Configuration alone. Is there an elegant way to organize this into classes?

e.g. current Pseudo code:

```
public class Annoying
{
   public string A {get; set;}
   ...
   public string Z {get; set;}

   public string ConfigA {get; set;}
   ...
   public string ConfigZ {get; set;}
}
```

I would like it to transform it like so:

```
public class Annoying
{
   public string A {get; set;}
   ...
   public string Z {get; set;}

   public Configuration Config {get; set;} // Contains all Config Properties

}
```

Is there a good way to do this on .NET 7 + EF Core Code first?

Comment: Are all properties valid for all rows? You could define a TPH, define a base class and specific child classes with nice property names. Then map each child column to the same column names...

Comment: @JeremyLakeman More or less unknown. I am discovering this  as I dig into the classes. The previous owners where less than stellar developers...

Answer (score 4):

You can look into using [Owned Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities). Something like:

```cs
public class Annoying
{
   public string A {get; set;}
   ...
   public string Z {get; set;}

   public Configuration Config {get; set;} // Contains all Config Properties
}

[Owned]
public class Configuration
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string Z { get; set; }
}
```

Note that by default it will lead to columns with consisting of prefix and property name split by underscore i.e. like `Config_A`, you can "remove" the prefix and/or underscore with custom column name mapping:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Annoying>()
    .OwnsOne(p => p.Config, 
        owned =>
        {
            // possibly should be automated:
            owned.Property(cfg => cfg.A).HasColumnName("ConfigA");
            owned.Property(cfg => cfg.B).HasColumnName("ConfigB");
            // ...
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a wrapper class? something like this

```
var AnnoyingGrouped = context.Annoying.GroupBy((x,y) => 
         x.ConfigA == y.ConfigA && x.ConfigB == y.ConfigB);
```

Now you have grouped by Configuration (the Key). How you use it is up to you.